# Forcibly disable the cache in Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I've been developing a couple of applications inside a Django CMS installation and have found it caches things well against my orders. This might not be such an issue in production but while I'm testing layouts, having to wait 10 minutes (or restart memcache) gets pretty boring.

Can I disable Django CMS's caching globally in my development settings?

Comment: Have you tried setting your `CACHES` setting to the dummy cache? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#dummy-caching-for-development

Answer (score 9):

Set the following settings locally:

```
CMS_PAGE_CACHE = False
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CACHE = False
CMS_PLUGIN_CACHE = False
```

If it still caches after that, then it could be a bug..